# backbone boilerplate render view issue

Tags: backbone.js

I am using the backbone-boilerplate/backbone-layoutmanager, and I am having issues re-rendering the view after calling place.fetch(). It seems to work fine the first time, but when I do fetch the second time, the "render" method is not getting called anymore.

Any hints would be helpful

thanks

pete

ROUTER

```
test: function() {
    var place = new Place.Model({
      place_id: place_id,
    });
    place.fetch().complete(function(){

    app.useLayout("main").setViews({
        ".place-detail": new Place.Views.Show({
          model: place
        })
      }).render();
   });
}
```

VIEW

```
initialize: function() {
  _.bindAll(this, "render");
 this.model.on("change", this.render, this);
}

render: function(manage) {
  return manage(this).render();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` is an async function which accepts an object with a `success` or `error` handler which will be called on completion. AFAIK `fetch` does not support the jQuery method of chaining with a `complete` handler, so you need to pass it an object with the proper `success` method set up if you want it called on completion.

Comment: thanks. but even if i use success and error the view doesn't get re-rendered with the new model data. im 100% sure that within the success i get the model data back. but somehow in here render is not getting called

    app.useLayout("main").setViews({
        ".place-detail": new Place.Views.Show({
                model: place
              })
            }).render();